# Streaming onlineradio streams using Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have a more general question; Is there ANY way to stream (for example) radio with the Web Audio API? I love the API, but I'd like to use it with a constant Stream of Data (SHOUTcast). 
I've searched for a way, but haven't found one.

Comment: This is not practical as there currently isn't a way to encode audio on the browser side with a codec, such as MP3 or FLAC.  The best you could do would be to send raw PCM data to a server where it would then be encoded and sent off to SHOUTcast/Icecast.  This would take a ton of bandwidth.

Comment: from the future: [@Brad mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23741147/629238) [Aurora.js](https://github.com/audiocogs/aurora.js), which seems to be doing something in that direction